# Visibility of text box depend on value of combo box

Tags: php, javascript, html, combobox

I want to set visibility of a text box depending on the value of a combo box's selected value.
This is my code:

```
<table width="500" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td><span> Name:</span></td>
    <td><input name="name"  type="text" id="name" size="40" class=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Email ID:</span></td>
    <td><input name="email"  type="email" id="email" size="40" class=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Select:</span></td>
    <td>
      <select id="edition">
        <option value="none" selected>----Select ----</option>
        <option id="1">A</option>
        <option id="2">B</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Number of Licenses</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="licenseNo" size="5" value="30" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the `licenseNo` text box visible if the value of combo box is B. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: are you ok to do via javascript?

Comment: yes. its better to use javascript

Comment: I updated answer. Just added tr and given id to it. Now you can hide entire row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use it like below. Just use value to get selected text

```
<table width="500" align="center" >
  <tr>
    <td><span> Name:</span></td>
    <td><input name="name"  type="text" id="name" size="40" class=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Email ID:</span></td>
    <td><input name="email"  type="email" id="email" size="40" class=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Select:</span></td>
    <td>
     <select id="edition" onchange="func()">
      <option value="none" selected >----Select ----</option>
      <option id="1">A</option>
      <option id="2">B</option>
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id ="trhide">
    <td><span>Number of Licenses</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="licenseNo" size="5" value="30" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function func() {
   var elem = document.getElementById("edition");

   if(elem.value == "B") {
      document.getElementById("trhide").style.visibility = "visible"; 
   } else {
     document.getElementById("trhide").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
   }
 }
</script>
```

see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CsCna/29/)

Answer (score 1):

Add event listener using JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function func() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("edition");
    if(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].innerHTML == "B") {
        document.getElementById("licenseNo").style.display = "";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("licenseNo").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<select id="edition" onchange="javascript:func();">
    ...
</select>
```

also don't forget to call `func()` at the start, when your page is just loaded.

Comment: can we do same for text also?
like i want text Number of Licenses visible after B is selected.

Comment: so when you want to hide textbox?

Comment: Yes, just wrap both the licenseNo field and the text in a single `div` or `span`, give that wrapper an id, and show/hide it.